# Trying to get the GUI program to recognize when a certain area is clicked? [Python]

Tags: python

I have a GUI program setup to play a matching game.

In my program, I have two buttons which work out fine because I have a Button Class to recognize that a button is created and when it is clicked. for the clicked portion, I have this in my code:

```
def isClicked(self, p):
        """Returns true if button active and Point p is inside"""
        if self.active == True and p.getX() <= self.xmax and p.getX() >= self.xmin and \
           p.getY() >= self.ymin and p.getY() <= self.ymax:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

However, this only works with buttons. I have in my program a 6x4 set up of cards on the screen. I click start game and the cards pop up, however the program crashes immediately after clicking start game and having the cards pop up because it says that `AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'isClicked'`
This makes sense, as my program is set up for buttons. So how can I get it so that my program registers when a user clicks something that's not a button?

In other words:
I want the user to click on a card and that card then draws up another card. But not sure how to get it to click wherever he wants and have it work when clicked on an actual card

```
for firstcard in range(6):
            firstrow = self.deck.dealCard()
            randomsuite = firstrow.getSuite()
            randomrank = firstrow.getRank()
            #Real image with face value of card
            realCard = Image(Point(xpos,ypos),"playingcards/"+ (randomsuite) + str(randomrank) +".gif")
            realCard.draw(win)
            #Red Back of card to cover image
            firstcard = Image(Point(xpos,ypos),"playingcards/b1fv.gif")
            firstcard.draw(win)
            #pushes the card to the right a bit
            xpos += 100 



while not Quitbutton.isClicked(p):
        #Start Game
        if StartGameButton.isClicked(p) and player == True:

            if first == True:
                Game.gameboard(win,150,125)
                if firstcard.isClicked(p):
                    firstcard.undraw()
                first = False
```

Comment: post the relevant parts of your code

Comment: @aless80, I've edited to show the main part I'm focusing on

Comment: what GUI library are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that `Image` is a class you can't directly modify.
In that case, you may extend it to be a clickable image using the following:

```
def ImageEx( Image ):
    def __init__( location, graphic ):
        super().__init__( location, graphic )

    def isClicked(self, p):
       # insert the click detection code here
```

Then simply use this class instead of the `Image` class:

```
        #Real image with face value of card
        realCard = ImageEx(Point(xpos,ypos),"playingcards/"+ (randomsuite) + str(randomrank) +".gif")
        realCard.draw(win)
        #Red Back of card to cover image
        firstcard = ImageEx(Point(xpos,ypos),"playingcards/b1fv.gif")
```

This will give you an interactive image with an `isClicked` method.

It might even be worth having an interactive object class that all your interactive objects can inherit from to give them the ability to be manipulated.

Comment: I never had an Image class, just straight up hard coded realcard = image(point(xpos,ypos), "playingcard")

So I added what you wrote, but when i add that, it kept saying a lot of my code doesn't work with it, and when i delete it, I'm still able to make the cards pop up on my game but still no clicking So i'm not sure how to implement the code you wrote